# Dylib (Dynamic Library) Objective-C iOS framework support

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, dynamic-library

I am very confused. Can an iOS objective-c app that is a framework itself include other dynamic frameworks that are supported in the AppStore. I am seeing very confusing and conflicting information elsewhere if anyone can clear this up for me.